# Color Coding a Vector Field

Tags: algorithm, vector, figure, polar-coordinates

I have a 2D vector field, and I would like to color code the vector field so that each vector direction shows up in a different color. Say my data are DataX and DataY. Currently, I am doing (in MATLAB):

```
R = DataX.^2 + DataY.^2;
theta1 = acos( DataX ./ R );
theta2 = asin( DataY ./ R );
surf(x,y,theta1); colormap jet; shading interp
figure; surf(x,y,theta2); colormap jet; shading interp
```

The issue I am having is that I cannot distinguish between vectors where either the x or y component is zero. For example, the color bar scale looks like (left, using arcsin, and right using arcos). When using arcsin, when DataY is zero (horizontal vector), arcsin(0) gives 0 regardless if the vector is pointing left or right.

[image]

Using the arctangent or arccotangent definitions of polar coordinates gives even worse results due to divide by zero errors. I am looking for an algorithm that would let me distinguish between the seemingly degenerate vectors. I have tried combining the arccos and arcsin results, but I have not been able to find a good way to do so.

I am also wondering how to extend this concept to 3D.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 2D, you can use atan2(DataY, DataX) to get an angle, and then map the angle to your color.  Use a cyclic colormap like 'hsv'

For 3D, you can normalize the vector to unit length and map the 3 components to red, green, and blue.

Comment: The issue still remains. DataX = 0, DataY = 1 gives angle of 0. DataX = 0, DataY = -1 gives angle of 0.

Comment: No.  atan2 maps (0,1) -> 0, (1,0) -> pi/2, (0,-1) -> pi, (-1,0) -> -pi/2

Comment: I think that's true mathematically. But computationally, the 0/1 or 0/-1 will be evaluated first, giving you zero. Then when we do atan(0) we get 0 regardless of what the y coordinate is. I am doing it in MATLAB. Is it different in an another language?

Comment: the whole point of using atan2 is so you don't have to do that division

Comment: Ok. I think I get. But I am using MATLAB where I don't have that capability. I think I could write a different version of arctan though maybe to take this into account.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. Thanks so much!